# How to use the external user control in asp project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp project, I have to call a custom user control to do some staff and the user control is outside of my project.

In .aspx page, I register the user control as below

```
<%@ Register Src="../Dev/popup/PopupSelection.ascx" TagName="PopupSelection" TagPrefix="checkSet"%>
```

and using it as

```
<checkSet:PopupSelection ID="popSelProject" runat="server"   PopupWidth="600px" PopupHeight="620px" AllowMultipleSelection="false"/>
```

For the code above, the popup success to show without any error.

However, when I try to call the method of the user control in page_load, it says

> 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for
>   'SetKeyValue' and no extension method
>   'SetKeyValue' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.UserControl' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

my aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popSelProject.SetKeyValue("key", "Value");
}
```

and my ascx file:

```
public partial class PopupSelection : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{ 
//.....
       public Dictionary<string, string> SetKeyValue    {
        set
        {
            ViewState["SetKeyValue"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["SetKeyValue"] != null)
                return (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewState["SetKeyValue"];
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                ViewState["SetKeyValue"] = dic;
                return dic;
            }
        }
    }
//.....
}
```

Comment: What is `popSelPrimarySubject`?

Comment: Is this a web application or a website? Is there a designer.aspx.cs file? What is the control type declared in the designer file?

Comment: @Neel updated. just copy the wrong part

Comment: @mason web application. The designer.aspx.cs file decalared it as    /// `<summary>
        /// popSelProject.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl popSelProject;`

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to modify designer file directly. But you might try changing it to the correct type and see if that fixes it. Can't hurt (if you're using source code control)

Comment: @mason It works if I modify my designer file directly, but why you say that is a bad idea? Will it bring any risk to my project?

Comment: It's VS's job to modify and you shouldn't normally mess with it. Sometimes it gets confused